# Setstate doesnt update UI Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to update visibilty of a widget in a statefulbuilder function , used to work completely fine, but now it only updates after I reload , I only put bunch of widgets in a different widgets to shorten the code

Comment: please provide snippet code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to reslove the issue

Comment: If the child widget is stateful widget then update that widget using didUpdateWidget() method.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you understand how to change widgets state;

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  bool visible = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          visible
              ? const Text(
                  'TEXT WIDGET BECOMES ONLY VISIBLE WHEN BOOLEAN VARIABLE VISIBLE BECOMES TRUE',
                )
              : const SizedBox(),
          Switch(
            value: visible,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                visible = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Every time you want to update something be it inside a *StatefulBuilder* function or be it in *StatefulWidget* you must use `setState(() {});`